# Calculating max wattage load for opto-triac

Tags: triac, opto-isolator

Are there any guidelines?

Do the guidelines differ depending on resistive/inductive/reactive loads?

For example, the [Vishay VO2223A](http://www.vishay.com/docs/81924/vo2223a.pdf) is rated up to 1A. At 110V it seems it can switch up to a 1 A x 110V = 110 watt load. I saw some [training material](http://dkc1.digikey.com/ca/en/tod/VishaySemiconductor/VO2223-VO2223A_NoAudio/VO2223-VO2223A_NoAudio.html) that indicated only up 22W load. Is this derating for safety? Is it to cover startup current draws?

I'd like to independently switch several AC devices: 50W heater, 23W CFL, 4W water pump.

Comment: The Vishay VO2223A you gave a link to is not a solid state relay but a optically isolated triac... Is this a question about the vishay or solid state relays?

Comment: Thanks. I'd be interested in the answer to both, though if I had to pick one, I'd say Vishay.

Comment: Could you perhaps describe what you're trying to do?  The two questions aren't terribly related...  solid-state relays and triacs aren't the same thing, so the answer to "both" questions is very different.

Comment: Edited question to provide more info.

Comment: Is there any answer to this? I want to control a 60W light bulb, and 120V @ 0.9A would seem to allow this, but I too see the mention of it only being able to control 22W, which seems crazy, as then what's the point of it being able to control 0.9A?

Answer (score 1):

It's a typical derating commonly used in various industries.  Primarily to ensure long term reliability.  And yes, that particular component can be referred to as a solid state relay.

Comment: What is a good guideline for derating? In this case max load = 25% of rated load?

Comment: Is there any answer to this? I would like to use the VO2223A to control a 60W light bulb, which it seems it should be able to do, except for that 22W thing